# Facebook - disable comments on post

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Can I use facebook API to make posts on a page where the comments are turned off.

In the apidoc https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v15.0/comment there is a can_comment field but is it readonly?

Comment: The individual comment is the wrong place to look, if anything, you would have to set this on the post level. But https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/post#fields mentions no such option anywhere I can see, so I would assume this is currently not possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I use the API to hide all comments ?

Comment: Only individual comments, as far as I know. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/comment/#hiding